# Where is the C compiler located on disk for Visual C++ 2008 Express?

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction

I'm trying to set up the [Hg-Git Mercurial Extension](http://hg-git.github.com/), which recommends using the C compiler for Microsoft Visual C++ 2008. I've installed Visual C++ 2008, but I can't figure out where the C compiler is located so that I can add it to my path.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Windows 7 / Vista:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe
```

Windows XP:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe
```

Comment: If anyone ends up here while trying to set up a MatLab xPC Target, just use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0` for the compiler path.

Comment: Not quite. `C:\Program Files (x86)` only exists in *64-bit* versions of Windows. For *32-bit* Windows it's the same `C:\Program Files` in XP / 7 / Vista / 10.

Answer (score 3):

[Currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475180/3211851) **is incorrect** in case when `Program Files` directory has been moved away (i.e. is now on another drive, `H:\Program Files` or `H:\Program Files (x86)`), which means it is no longer available in default path (`C` drive).

**Visual Studio 2008**

Windows **XP 32-bit** (x86):

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe

Windows **Vista 32-bit** and later Windows operating systems (x86):

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe

Windows **XP 64-bit** (x64):

> %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe

Windows **Vista 64-bit** and later Windows operating systems (x64):

> %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe

Comment: What if you installed a different ProgramFiles and not the primary one no matter where %ProgramFiles(x86)% points to. I think the accepted answer is not bad, it only doesn't handle an edge case, also yours could be inccorent in edge cases.

Comment: But I like your perspective for both 32/64 OSs.

Comment: Can you please edit your comment for Windows 10? I can't see %ProgramFiles(x86)% Environment variable in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

**Related Answer for those who may be using Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 "ultimate" on a Windows 8.1 machine and are trying to locate the version of your current C++ compiler; you should be able to navigate to:**

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin>*

**and open a command prompt as administrator.**

**Then within the administrative command prompt, you can enter the following command:**

*"cl -option"*

**and hit return. It will look like this just before you press return**:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin>cl -option*

**The version of your C++ compiler should then show up  within the command prompt something like this:**

*Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.30723 for x86
Copyright (C)*

*Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.*