# Rcpp on windows with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, r, visual-studio, rcpp

I have Visual Studio 2015 on my windows 10 and I would like to use Rcpp for developping my own package.
Now I get an error "status 127" which means, according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131083/install-package-on-windows-error-compilation-failed-for-package-cldr), that the C++ compiler is not found.
I don't want to install RTools because I think I have already a C++ compiler since Visual studio can make it ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475159/where-is-the-c-compiler-located-on-disk-for-visual-c-2008-express)).

Now my problem is : how to locate this compiler and how to point R onto it ? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616983/building-r-packages-using-alternate-gcc) should help me but I cannot figure out how to properly follow it.

There may also be some good references [here about R PATH](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) and [here for C++ and Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60k1461a.aspx). I recognize I don't understand a lot of things about these config pages.

thanks

Comment: Please see [question 2.9 of the Rcpp FAQ](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Indeed I am scared of installing RTools because of possible interference with the current c++ compiler. But so there is no such risk indeed ?